# Gagliardo-Nirenberg type inequality for fractional relativistic Laplacian operator?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, interpolation, fractional-calculus

In [1], authors note that by the seminal approach of M. Weinstein in [2] and [3], there is a non-trivial solution $Q\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$ which optimizes next Gagliardo-Nirenberg type inequality:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|u|^{\alpha+2}\,dx\leq C_{\alpha,s}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|(-\Delta)^{s/2}u|^2\,dx\right)^{\alpha/4s}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|u|^2\,dx\right)^{\alpha(2s-1)/4s+1},$$
for some admissible $\alpha$. I think the relativistic generalization of this inequality should hold as next form:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|u|^{\alpha+2}\,dx\leq C_{\alpha,s,m}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|(-\Delta+m^2)^{s/2}u|^2\,dx\right)^{\alpha/4s}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|u|^2\,dx\right)^{\alpha(2s-1)/4s+1},$$
with an optimizer in $H^s(\mathbb{R})$. But I am afraid that I cannot find a suitable reference. So I wonder if the existence of this optimizer proven already, or reasonable enough to deduce easily somehow, otherwise I can try the same approach of M. Weinstein.

Thank you in advance.

**References**

[1] Frank, Rupert L., and Enno Lenzmann. "Uniqueness of non-linear ground states for fractional Laplacians in R." Acta mathematica 210.2 (2013): 261-318.

[2] Weinstein, Michael I. "Modulational stability of ground states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations." SIAM journal on mathematical analysis 16.3 (1985): 472-491.

[3] Weinstein, Michael I. "Existence and dynamic stability of solitary wave solutions of equations arising in long wave propagation." Communication in partial Differential Equation 12.10 (1987): 1133-1173.

Comment: Is your question about the existence of the optimizer, or is your question about the validity of the inequality itself? For the inequality: if you use the obvious definition $(-\Delta + m^2)^{s/2} u = \mathcal{F}^{-1}( (|\xi|^2 + m^2)^{s/2} \hat{u})$ then the inequality holds because $$ \| (-\Delta)^{s/2} u\|_{L^2} \leq \|(-\Delta + m^2)^{s/2} u\|_{L^2} $$

Comment: The fact that the optimizer exists should be by now an application of Concentration-Compactness type arguments. Standard treatments usually work with the case $s = 1$, but the "concentration compactness" part of the argument is generally independent of the "sobolev inequality" part, so modifying the arguments found in, e.g. Tintarev's _Concentration compactness_ textbook shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, my question was indeed vague. I was more interested in the existence of the optimizer. Thank you so much for the reference, I will check it out. Have a great day.

Comment: As a side remark: since you wrote down the scale invariant version of the inequality, for concentration compactness you need to account for both translation in $\mathbb{R}$ and for scaling. Even if you take the main concentration compactness method as a black box, filling in _all_ the details would still take at least 1 entire afternoon and 5 or more pages.

Comment: @WillieWong That would be awesome if I can do it in one afternoon :) Thank you for your help!